# Sensitivity analysis with R: How can I make my own plot

Tags: r, plot

Do you know the method to do my own plot of sensitivity analysis result using R?

For example (using `fast99()` and a toy model):

```
> library(sensitivity)
> x <- fast99(model = ishigami.fun, factors = 3, n = 1000,
              q = "qunif", q.arg = list(min = -pi, max = pi))
> print(x)
> Call:
> fast99(model = ishigami.fun, factors = 3, n = 1000, q = "qunif",
         q.arg = list(min = -pi, max = pi))
> Model runs: 3000 
> Estimations of the indices:
>    first order     total order
> X1 3.076874e-01   0.5506015
> X2 4.419659e-01   0.4697538
> X3 3.431342e-29   0.2391275
```

I just want to pick the data of the estimations of the indices (`X1`, `X2`, `X3`), to put them in a matrix...
Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot? What would be the x and y values?

Comment: X values : X1, X2, X3 and y values : fisrt order and total order values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could work. First, a helper function to turn the `fast99` data into a data.frame

```
as.data.frame.fast99 <- function(x, ...) {
    if (!is.null(x$y)) {
        S <- data.frame(X=colnames(x$X), x$D1/x$V, 1 - x$Dt/x$V)
        colnames(S)[-1] <- c("first.order", "total.order")
        S
    }
}
```

And now we plot the data. (Here I use the `ggplot` library but you could easily use others)

```
dd<-as.data.frame(x)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(x=X)) + 
   geom_point(aes(y=first.order, color="first")) + 
   geom_point(aes(y=total.order, color="total")) + 
   scale_color_manual(values=c(first="red",total="blue"), name="order")
```

[image]